# How can I run sails console without a webserver (using any ports)?

Tags: node.js, heroku, console, webserver, sails.js

I have a Sails server running, and I want to execute some commands from inside of lifted Sails.

The problem is, then I run `sails console` - it bootstraps another instance of Sails, and trying to load another webserver next to existing, by default using the same ports.

By some environment limits, I can use only one port at the time. So I cannot load another webserver on the same machine.

Is there a way how to run `sails console` without using any ports?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an option. Use `sails console --dontLift`

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I wanted! I'm surprised why is it not documented?

Comment: yeah sails lacks documentation. I had do dig into their source code to find this option.

Comment: Im also surprised! Found it only in the changelog: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0125

Answer (score 0):

Running console without port is I belive not possible at all.

Add inside package json npm script to run console on another port (or if you have sails installed globally just run sails console --port xxxx).

Part of my package json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "console": "sails console --port 1338",
    "test": "mocha",
    "docs": "rimraf public/docs && apidoc -i config/routes -o public/docs"
  },
```

As you can see... npm run console will run sails console on port 1338 while deafult port of my app is 1337...

Comment: As I mentioned before, I cannot use another port. It must be a way to run it without `http` hook.